# Bazel not running flutter correctly

Tags: flutter, bazel

I'm trying to execute a flutter command using `bazel`. This is my `BUILD.bazel` file:

```
genrule(
    name = "flutter_build",
    srcs = [
        "//:root_filegroup"
    ],
    outs = ["out.txt"],
    cmd = "flutter build ipa --export-method development"
)
```

The command `flutter build ipa --export-method development` works perfectly if I run it directly in my `iterm`, but for some reason the same command in `bazel` returns a permission error:

```
Flutter failed to open a file at "/Users/rlanhe/tools/flutter/flutter/bin/cache/lockfile".
Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has read/write permissions for the current user.
Try running:
  sudo chown -R $(whoami) /Users/rlanhe/tools/flutter/flutter/bin/cache/lockfile
```

Well, doesn't make sense to me, since that folder already have correct permission and I'm able to run the command outside `bazel`.

Answer (score 4):

Integrating Flutter/Dart and Bazel is likely a large amount of work.

There's an issue here about it:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19680

And it looks like there are some dart rules here:
https://github.com/cbracken/rules_dart

The immediate issue you're running into is that Bazel runs each action (i.e. build step) in a sandbox, so unless an input to the action is declared, it's not going to be in the sandbox. You can maybe get further by adding `tags = ["no-sandbox"]` to the genrule, (see https://bazel.build/reference/be/common-definitions#common.tags).

This is essentially running one build system inside another, and this isn't going get the caching and incrementality benefits of Bazel, because Bazel has no insight into what happens inside the genrule. Unless you have some higher-level plans to integrate this into a larger repository that uses Bazel, there isn't much benefit here compared to running `flutter` directly or in a shell script.

Comment: I agree with you that using `genrule` would not be a good solution but we pretend to migrate it to bazel rules using flutter in the future. BTW, not clear to me what you mean with `unless an input to the action is  declared, it's not going to be in the sanbox`.

Comment: Great, just wanted to make sure all the caveats are known. Regarding "unless an input to the action is  declared, it's not going to be in the sanbox", Bazel only puts the files that are declared as inputs to the action (like `srcs` for genrule) in the sandbox. So for files like `/Users/rlanhe/tools/flutter/flutter/bin/cache/lockfile`, Bazel doesn't know about them and won't put them in the sandbox, so the action (i.e. `flutter`) won't be able to find them. There might be lots of files like that, so it's easiest to just disable sandboxing (though you could probably find all the needed files).

Comment: Thanks got it. Adding `no-sandbox` tag worked.