# How to build flutter apps with bazel

Tags: android, flutter, bazel

How can I build my dummy app with bazel.
Or how can I build the app in Android folder with bazel in flutter dummy app.I tried to do this it gave me an error **desugar** checking not currently supported in Bazel.

Answer (score 1):

You can start exploring it from [this Repo](https://github.com/scalio/bazel-flutter) . Already Most of the community members are working on it and the references are [#1](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19680) [#2](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/58082). And for [dart rules](https://dart%20rules%20here:%20https://github.com/cbracken/rules_dart). [Stack references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72369756/bazel-not-running-flutter-correctly)